# pandas - plotting integration with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

Given this data frame:

```
xlabel = list('xxxxxxyyyyyyzzzzzz')
fill= list('abc'*6)
val = np.random.rand(18)
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'xlabel':xlabel, 'fill':fill, 'val':val})
```

This is what I'm aiming at: http://matplotlib.org/mpl_examples/pylab_examples/barchart_demo.png

Applied to my example, `Group` would be `x`, `y` and `z`, `Gender` would be `a`, `b` and `c`, and `Scores` would be `val`.

I'm aware that in pandas plotting integration with matplotlib is still work in progress, so is it possible to do it directly in matplotlib?

Comment: note sure what you mean by work in progress: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#bar-plots, saying that not sure how to do the quantile ticks (someone will though) :)

Comment: @Andy Hayden: I was under the impression that not all matplotlib functionalities were working in pandas yet, given the Note at the top of the page you mentioned

Comment: You didn't need the quantile ticks?

Comment: @Andy Hayden: I posted an answer including the error bars, although I'm sure there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
df.groupby(['fill', 'xlabel']).mean().unstack().plot(kind='bar')
```

or

```
df.pivot_table(rows='fill', cols='xlabel', values='val').plot(kind='bar')
```

You can brake it apart and fiddle with the labels and columns and title, but I think this basically gives you the plot you wanted.

For the error bars currently you'll have to go to the mpl directly.

```
mean_df = df.pivot_table(rows='fill', cols='xlabel',
                         values='val', aggfunc='mean')
err_df = df.pivot_table(rows='fill', cols='xlabel',
                        values='val', aggfunc='std')

rows = len(mean_df)
cols = len(mean_df.columns)
ind = np.arange(rows)
width = 0.8 / cols
colors = 'grb'

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, col in enumerate(mean_df.columns):
    ax.bar(ind + i * width, mean_df[col], width=width,
           color=colors[i], yerr=err_df[col], label=col)

ax.set_xticks(ind + cols / 2.0 * width)
ax.set_xticklabels(mean_df.index)
ax.legend()
```

But there will be an enhancement, probably in the 0.13: [issue 3796](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3796)

Comment: Is it possible to extend your code by including the error bars? I've posted an answer with possible solution, but there must be a better way.

Comment: @user2635863 For the error bars you'll have to use the matplotlib library directly. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This was the only solution I found for displaying the error bars:

```
means = df.groupby(['fill', 'xlabel']).mean().unstack()
x_mean,y_mean,z_mean = means.val.x, means.val.y,means.val.z

sems = df.groupby(['fill','xlabel']).aggregate(stats.sem).unstack()
x_sem,y_sem,z_sem = sems.val.x, sems.val.y,sems.val.z

ind = np.array([0,1.5,3])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
width = 0.35
bar_x = ax.bar(ind, x_mean, width, color='r', yerr=x_sem, ecolor='r')
bar_y = ax.bar(ind+width, y_mean, width, color='g', yerr=y_sem, ecolor='g')
bar_z = ax.bar(ind+width*2, z_mean, width, color='b', yerr=z_sem, ecolor='b')

ax.legend((bar_x[0], bar_y[0], bar_z[0]), ('X','Y','Z'))
```

I'd be happy to see a neater approach to tackle the problem though, possibly as an extension of Viktor Kerkez answer.